# How to prevent overlap of badges after increasing their size in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to create badges in bootstrap with a larger font size. But the problem is the badges overlap in a smaller screen How can I avoid this. Here's the code

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div class="container">
  <h2>Contextual Label Classes</h2>
  <p>Contextual classes can be used to color the label.</p>  
  <span class="label label-default" style="font-size: 1.25em;" >Default Label</span>
<span class="label label-default" style="font-size: 1.25em;" >Default Label</span>
<span class="label label-default" style="font-size: 1.25em;" >Default Label</span>
<span class="label label-default" style="font-size: 1.25em;" >Default Label</span>
<span class="label label-default" style="font-size: 1.25em;" >Default Label</span>
<span class="label label-default" style="font-size: 1.25em;" >Default Label</span>
<span class="label label-default" style="font-size: 1.25em;" >Default Label</span>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6nrdtku1/

Comment: You can increase label line height to 2 (line-height: 2)

Comment: That works..thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for this and do a styling like:

```
.yourClass{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin-bottom: .5em; /*Or whatever looks good*/
}
```